# Matlab, plot with errorbars

Tags: matlab

I'm pretty new to Matlab and I would like to make a plot with errorbars. I have the errors in a vector expressed in % of the measured values. I have tried to use Matlab's errorbar but it is only shifting the plot in a strange way.

Comment: Edit your question and add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard [usage](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) is `errorbar(x,y,yerr, ...options...)`.

In your case sounds like `yerr = y.*percenterr/100`